# Dojo Design Elements in Modal Windows in XPages

Tags: css, dojo, xpages

I have created a modal and then put some design elements in it. Every components work great except Dojos. They are working but when i click on it to chose date the windows stays behind of modal. so I can not control it. I tried z-index or similar thinks but I could not succeeded. I could not get it front. This problem happens only in Modal. Otherwise All of Dojo elements works 100%. So I do now know Where to start digging :(

```
<!-- This codes below is the whole modal dialog codes.. --> 
<xp:link escape="true" id="addUnvan" styleClass="text-primary list-icons-item"
                        rendered="#{javascript:document1.isEditable()}">
                        <xp:this.attrs>
                            <xp:attr name="type" value="button"></xp:attr>
                            <xp:attr name="data-target" value="#modal_theme_custom"></xp:attr>
                            <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="modal"></xp:attr>
                            <xp:attr name="data-popup" value="popover"></xp:attr>
                            <xp:attr name="data-trigger" value="hover"></xp:attr>
                            <xp:attr name="data-content"
                                value="Çalışanın görevi değiştiyse onun eski görevini yeni görevinden bir gün önce bitecek şekilde kapatır. Yeni unvan eklerim.."></xp:attr>
                            <xp:attr name="data-original-title" value="Ne Mi Yaparım?"></xp:attr>
                            <xp:attr name="data-placement" value="right"></xp:attr>
                        </xp:this.attrs>
                        <i class="icon-stack-plus"></i>
                    </xp:link>
<!-- This codes below is the whole modal dialog codes.. -->
<div id="modal_theme_custom" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"
        style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <xp:div id="divUnvanContent" styleClass="card">
                    <div class="card-header header-elements-inline">
                        <h5 class="card-title">
                            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField5" value="#{unvanDoc.AdSoyad}"
                                rendered="false">
                            </xp:text>
                        </h5>
                        <div class="header-elements">
                            <div class="list-icons">
                                 
                                 

                                 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <xp:div styleClass="bootstrap-duallistbox-container row moveonselect">
                                <xp:div styleClass="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                     

                                    <xp:div id="divGTarih" styleClass="form-group row">
                                        <xp:label value="Geçerlilik Tarihi:" id="label2"
                                            styleClass="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-md-3"></xp:label>
                                        <xp:div styleClass="col-lg-9 col-md-9">
                                            <xe:djDateTextBox styleClass="form-control pickadate picker__input"
                                                id="BasTarih" value="#{document1.BasTarih}">

                                                <xe:this.converter>
                                                    <xp:convertDateTime type="date"
                                                        dateStyle="short">
                                                    </xp:convertDateTime>
                                                </xe:this.converter>
                                            </xe:djDateTextBox>
                                            <xe:djDateTextBox id="BitTarih" value="#{document1.BitTarih}"
                                                styleClass="ml-6">
                                                <xe:this.converter>
                                                    <xp:convertDateTime type="date"
                                                        dateStyle="short">
                                                    </xp:convertDateTime>
                                                </xe:this.converter>
                                            </xe:djDateTextBox>
                                        </xp:div>
                                    </xp:div> 
                                </xp:div> 
                            </xp:div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </xp:div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

**UPDATE**
I could not find the correct z-index property of DojoComponent I mean correct class. Please find the picture of code. When click on it I see lots of classes. I have tried so many classes but I am tired of trying :((( is there any clue that i can follow..

Thanks in advance...
[image]

Comment: Can you add example code that includes the code for the modal?

Comment: I have added codes of modal dialog and how i call the modal dialog.

Comment: I think It's a css problem but I really do not know where to look :((

Comment: Check the CSS styling for the date picker popup.  Examine the CSS of the date picker popup, and set the z-index to a higher number.